# Escaping parenthesis in jquery contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I have:

```
item.find('div:contains(' + name + ')')
```

However, in some cases, name contains parenthesis. In one case, name has this value:

```
"brown (ok xl (1))"
```

And item.find('div:contains(' + name + ')') doesn't work. The parenthesis are the problem. How to escape them?

Comment: Try this: `"brown \(ok xl \(1\)\)"`

Comment: Shouldn't be escaped with _double_ \ in the _selector_?

Comment: @PraveenKumar name get its values in runtime.

Comment: It will be better if you change title from `Escaping parenthesis in jquery find` to `Escaping parenthesis in jquery contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem few days ago, but for some weird reason @Zeta's solution didn't work for me so I came up with

```
name = name.replace(/(\(|\)).*/g,"");
item.find("div:contains(" + name +")");
```

It isn't perfect but it works :)

**EDIT**

A better RegEX:

```
name = "(d)test thingie(assaf)(asdads".replace(/\(([^\)])*\)/g,"$1 ").replace(/\(|\)(.)*/g,"$1 ");
```

If you want to eliminate everything in between parenthesis so that contains work you can use:

```
name = "(d)test thingie(assaf)(asdads".replace(/\(([^\)])*\)/g,"").replace(/\(|\)(.)*/g,"");
```

Comment: For this example: "(D) Room".replace(/(\(|\)).*/g, "") returns "". Now what?

Comment: added to new regex use whichever solves your problem, second one should!

Answer (score 4):

To use any of the meta-characters `( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^'{|}~)` as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\` For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Here is a function to escape special characters and return a valid jQuery selector. Pass your string to this function before use:

```
function jqSelector(str)
{
    return str.replace(/([;&,\.\+\*\~':"\!\^#$%@\[\]\(\)=>\|])/g, '\\$1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. [(source)](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

So simply use

```
item.find('div:contains(\'' + name + '\')')
/* or */
item.find('div:contains("' + name + '")')
```

Note that you need to escape additional quotation marks inside `name` if you have any.

Comment: It doesn't escape parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement your own solution for this (anymore?). Use [jQuery.escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/):

```js
console.log($.escapeSelector('this selector\'s got (many) special chars!@#$#@#$.***'));
// this\ selector\'s\ got\ \(many\)\ special\ chars\!\@\#\$\#\@\#\$\.\*\*\*

$($.escapeSelector('this selector\'s got (many) special chars!@#$#@#$.***'))
// { "length": 0, "prevObject": { /* ... */ } }


$('this selector\'s got (many) special chars!@#$#@#$.***')
// Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: this selector's got (many) special chars!@#$#@#$.***
```